# Hover effect over image as a link ideas

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image on my page which I use as a link. I am trying to get an effect where when the hover is on the image it will become a little darker (transparent dark) and over the image will appear text saying "View". I am using Bootstrap, so it needs to be responsive.

I tried to do `categorieimg:a hover` in CSS but it doesn't seems to respond. If it can be done with jQuery, all suggestions welcomed.

My HTML:

```
@extends ('master') 

@section('content') 
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 class="text-center">Myhero Shop</h1> <br><br>
    </div> 
</div>  
<div class="row"> 

    @if ($categories)
    @foreach($categories as $category) 
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 text-center"> 
        <h3 >{{ $category['title'] }} </h3>   
        <p class><a href="{{ url('shop/'. $category['url']) }}" class="categorieimg"><img width="250" src="{{ asset('images/' . $category['image']) }}"></a></p>  
        <p>{!! $category['article']!!}</p>  

    </div> 
    @endforeach 
    @else 
    <div class="col-md-12"> <br><br>
        <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 18px"><b>No categories found...</b></p>
        <div 
            @endif
    </div>
    @endsection
```

Comment: Can you put css? Ary you trying to change background-color on hover while there is an img?

Comment: @AbdullahAlemadi yes thats what I am trying to reach.At this point I have only 1 line in css which I tried and doesn't work . My css: .categorieimg:hover{ 
background-color:#269abc;
}

Comment: First, did you add a background-color behind the image? and is the img .PNG ?

Comment: The image is jpeg .What do you mean behind the image?

Comment: You can't add bg-color of an img that has an img inside it and not PNG, by PNG I mean it has no background to the color you want can show! I can't explain the obvious  :(

Comment: Ok.Is there other way to reach the effect I asked about?

Comment: You can use PNG icon and change the bg-color on hover, or you can change the icon itself on hover, or you can scale the element on hover. You have many options.

Comment: I don't understand . Are you saying that if Ill change my image from jpeg to png and use the same css line I used before categorieimg:hover{ background-color:#269abc; }  it will change the color on hover?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to achieve what you want, you should use PNG image not JPEF.
Because JPEG images will take the full space of the element and you can't show the background-color anywhere.

**See this working demo.**

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

img:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/commerce-5/100/.svg-6-128.png" alt="">
```

Comment: I did as you said , unfortunately its still doesn't work.